# Yet again findFragmentByTag() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have read innumerable SO articles on the issue of findFragmentByTag() returning null, and after several days, I still cant't get it to work.  So I'm hear to post my own question on it.

I have one container and three fragments.  I want to be able to swipe/fling from A-->B-->C-->A-->  etc or backwards.  That is, left swipe or right swipe to cycle through the fragment panels.
I have all of this working.  But my problem is that once I swipe through the full cycle from A back to A, all of my connections to the TextView fields no longer work (there are numerous live updating text fields in these fragments).  That is the updates are no longer there and I can no longer see changes to the fields; I can `setText("foo")` to a field, but the new value no longer shows up.  When the fragment shows up it no longer has any textview updates.  As if the original instance of the fragment has been lost somewhere and the instance being shown is a new instance.
Based on logcat results, I think this is happening.  In fact, findFragmentByTag is *always* returning null, and hence the code is creating new fragment every time for every swipe.

I would like to hold on to each instance (A, B and C), so that they hold state and ongoing updates to them are visible as I swipe through the fragments.
Here is the full code file:

```
package com.company.myApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment_ProgressBar extends Fragment {
    final static String TAG = "Fragment_ProgressBar";
    final static String FRAGMENT_TAG_SUMMARY     = "Fragment_Summary";
    final static String FRAGMENT_TAG_PROGRESSBAR = "Fragment_ProgressBar";
    final static String FRAGMENT_TAG_TIME  = "Fragment_Time";
    final static String DIRECTION_LEFT  = "DIRECTION_LEFT";
    final static String DIRECTION_RIGHT = "DIRECTION_RIGHT";
    public final static String CURRENT_FRAGMENT = FRAGMENT_TAG_PROGRESSBAR;
    final Fragment thisFragment = this;

    public Fragment_ProgressBar(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1,
                                           MotionEvent event2,
                                           float velocityX,
                                           float velocityY) {
                        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                        final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                        try {
                            if (Math.abs(event1.getY() - event2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                                return false;
                            if (event1.getX() - event2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Right to Left");
                                showFragment_RightToLeft(FRAGMENT_TAG_TIMECIRCLE);
                            } else if (event2.getX() - event1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Left to Right");
                                showFragment_LeftToRight(FRAGMENT_TAG_SUMMARY);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // nothing
                        }
                        return super.onFling(event1, event2, velocityX, velocityY);
                    }
                });

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress_bar, container, false);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    private Fragment getNewFragment(String name){
        Log.i(TAG,String.format("Fragment (%s) not found; creating new instance.", name));
        switch (name) {
            case FRAGMENT_TAG_SUMMARY:
                return new Fragment_Summary();
            case FRAGMENT_TAG_PROGRESSBAR:
                return new Fragment_ProgressBar();
            case FRAGMENT_TAG_TIME:
                return new Fragment_Time();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void showFragment_LeftToRight(String nextFragmentNameTag)
    {

        Fragment nextFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(nextFragmentNameTag);
        if (nextFragment == null)
            nextFragment = getNewFragment(nextFragmentNameTag);
        if (nextFragment == null)
            return;

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
        ft.remove(thisFragment);
        ft.add(R.id.overview_fragment_container, nextFragment, nextFragmentNameTag);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    }
    private void showFragment_RightToLeft(String nextFragmentNameTag)
    {
        Fragment nextFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(nextFragmentNameTag);
        if (nextFragment == null)
            nextFragment = getNewFragment(nextFragmentNameTag);
        if (nextFragment == null)
            return;

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right, R.animator.slide_out_left);
        ft.replace(R.id.overview_fragment_container, nextFragment, nextFragmentNameTag);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried putting the findFragmentByTag() call in the main activity and it make no difference.  Still null.

Comment: why are you looking for the fragments in a private fragment manager  getChildFragmentManager() and yet transacting it in the main fragment manager getFragmentManager()?? Secondly how do you expect the fragment to still remain when you are calling remove and replace??

Comment: Ignorance!  The answer is simple ignorance!  I just changed to getChildManager and it now works.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to put your answer in the answer block, I'd be happy to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you are looking for the fragments as if they were attached as child fragments to the `Fragment_ProgressBar`, all your fragment are still managed by the activity fragment manager, so you're looking for the fragments in the wrong place.

Secondly, you are removing old fragment from the fragment manager every time you call `FragmentTransaction.remove()` or `FragmentTransaction.replace()` while performing a transaction.

I will also suggest you add/reattach the new fragment and detach old fragment (the fragment is removed from the UI, however its state is still being actively managed by the fragment manager).

Comment: If I want to add a new fragment *and* store the old one, what is the proper order?  Don't I need to `remove` or `replace` the old fragment before I `add` the new one?

Comment: If you call `remove` or use `replace` then the fragment manager will not store the old one (unless you want to keep the fragment instance which might not give you a smooth flow). Just detach old one then add(new)/reattach(pre-exisiting) one.